# Why $(this) from jQuery isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out why my `$(this)` from jQuery isn't working in this case:

```
<ul>                
    <li class="tabs-li-js ui-tabs-tab ui-tabs-active">
      <a href="#fragment-1" class="anchor-tabs" id="ui-id-1">Online Investing</a>
    </li>

    <li class="tabs-li-js ui-tabs-tab">
      <a href="#fragment-2" class="anchor-tabs" id="ui-id-2">Guided Investing</a>
    </li>              
</ul>
```

And this is the js function:

```
var $tabsLiJs = $('.tabs-li-js');
var productDescriptionMob = function() {
    $tabsLiJs.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $tabsLiJs.each(function(i, el) {
            if ($(el).hasClass('ui-tabs-active')) {
                $('[data-action="show'+i+'"]').show();
            } else {
                $('[data-action="show'+i+'"]').hide();
            }
        });

    });
};
```

The way it is above works perfectly.

As you may see, in the second line there is an element: `$tabsLiJs` which has an on click event. Then, in the `.each` function is where I am trying to add the `$(this)` for a matter of context. But it is not working.

**I am trying to use the this here:**

```
$(this).each(function(i, el) {
     if ($(el).hasClass('ui-tabs-active')) {
          $('[data-action="show'+i+'"]').show();
     } else {
          $('[data-action="show'+i+'"]').hide();
     }
});
```

What can that be?
Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no `$(this)` in your code. Furthermore, what does `not working` mean?

Comment: Is productDescriptionMob called from within your doc ready?

Comment: What is `this` suppose to reference?

Comment: Questions without **a clear problem statement** (_"isn't working"_ is not clear at all...) are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @empiric I added it already.

Comment: `this` will reference the `.tabs-li-js` element the user just clicked on. So, using jquery.each is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas `$tabsLiJS` is a jquery object containing all DOM objects that carry the given class name, the `this` in the click-function will only refer to the one actually clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your following function:

```
$('.tabs-li-js').each(function(i, el) {
     if ($(el).hasClass('ui-tabs-active')) {
          $('[data-action="show'+i+'"]').show();
     } else {
          $('[data-action="show'+i+'"]').hide();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**In this case, the "this" keyword is refering to the "productDescriptionMob" object.**

The "this" keyword has 4 possible ways of being defined in Javascript:

1 - Global context. When the keyword "this" is not inside a declared object, it's considered to be in the global scope, and its value is the global object (or the window object in most cases).

**2 - Implicit/Object: When the keyword "this" is inside a declared object, it's value will be the closest parent object declared.**

3 - Explicit binding: When the methods "call", "apply" or "bind" are used, the first parameter defines what the keyword "this" value will be inside the function.

4 - New objects: When the key word "this" is inside a function which is called using the keyword "new" before it, the "this" keyword will refer to the newly created object.

Your code is set in the second case, Implicit/Object. It means that, since the closest parent object declared before the keyword "this" is the "productDescriptionMob" object, so it is its value.

More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this